# Boolean return value?

Tags: python, boolean, return-value

```
def main():

    num = int(input('Please enter an odd number: '))

    if False:
        print('That was not a odd number, please try again.')

    else:
        print('Congrats, you know your numbers!')

def number():

    if (num / 2) == 0:
        return True,num

    else:
        return False,num


main()
```

I am trying to make it so that if the number entered is odd, it congratulates the user. If not then it should tell them to try again. I am trying to return the Boolean value to main and then when I try to use the code in the main function to prompt the user, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try use `num % 2 == 0` but not `(num / 2) == 0`

Comment: Well, for one, you defined `number()` but don't actually use it.

Comment: Your use of functions and return values is not correct, nor the interpretation of how boolean values are used.  There is no control flow in your program, and I recommend some beginner python tutorials to get you started before tackling something like this on your own.

Comment: Well, what do you expect `if False:` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
num_entry = int(input('Please enter an odd number: '))


def number():
    return num_entry % 2 == 0

def main():

    if number() == True:
        print('Sorry, please try again.')

    else:
        print('Nice! You know your numbers!')

number()

main()
```

This should work!

Comment: Finally! Sorry about the horrible code everyone but this is what I was looking for originally for an answer. Now to understand what I did wrong...

Answer (score 6):

Your functions are very odd and I'm not talking about numbers that aren't divisible by 2. Try this:

```
num = int(input('Please enter an odd number: '))

if num % 2 == 0:
    print('Better luck next time??') # no really, you should go back to school (;

else:
    print('Genius!!!')
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. Either way, you fail? If you enter an even number, it says `'You failed'`, but if you enter an odd number (correct), it says `'Better luck next time??'`?

Comment: Sorry. The code makes sense the responses don't. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does look odd like Malik Brahimi mentioned. This may be because you are trying to write your python code like Java, which requires a main method. There is no such requirement in python.

If you would like to have your check for the "odd-ness" of the number wrapped in a defined function that you can call elsewhere, you should try writing it like this.

```
def odd_check(number):

    if number % 2 == 0: 
#This is the check the check formula, which calculates the remainder of dividing number by 2
        print('That was not an odd number. Please try again.')

    else:
        print('Congrats, you know your numbers!')


num = int(input('Please enter an odd number: ')) #where variable is stored.

odd_check(num) #This is where you are calling the previously defined function. You are feeding it the variable that you stored.
```

If you would like a piece of code that will continue to ask your user to enter a number until they get it right, try something like this:

```
while True: #This ensures that the code runs until the user picks an odd number

    number = int(input('Please enter an odd number: ')) #where variable is stored.

    if number % 2 == 0: #the check formula, which calculates the remainder of dividing num by 2
        print('That was not an odd number. Please try again.')

    else:
        print('Congrats, you know your numbers!')
        break #This stops the "while" loop when the "else" condition is met.
```